# pyspark how to drop rdd column like in scala .drop

Tags: python, scala, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

file videos.csv as below

```
2482cal-2792-48da,Action,Comedy 
099acca-8888-48ca,Action,Comedy
```

In Spark Scala can drop RDD column 1 with `.drop(1)` to drop for all rows rdd column 1 as example `482cal-2792-48da` and `099acca-8888-48ca`.

I would like to know how to do this in PySpark rdd in PySpark as given below in line 2 code

Spark Scala

```
val records = sc.textFile("file:///home/videos.csv")
val words = records.flatMap(record => record.split(",").drop(1))**
```

**PySpark**

```
videos_rdd = sc.textFile("/user/spark_dataset/datastax_ds320/videos.csv", 4)
videos_rdd_flat = videos_rdd.flatMap(lambda t:t.split(","))**
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use splicing:

```
videos_rdd.flatMap(lambda t: t.split(",")[1:])
```